# how can we make a signal out of a 2 pin mic output

Tags: pcb-design, soldering, component-selection, passive-components

ok im looking to make this type of setup so that i can use its output pin to read via analog.

[image]

this is the mic i got and would like to make that 3rd pinout which as you can see it only has 2 and this is how it comes as a replacement

[image]

what kind of passive components if any do i need to make this happen ? or how would i solder this mic in a way that i can get power ground and signal/output ?

Comment: Do you have access to schematics of the pcb shown in the first picture? Or do you have the actual pcb in hands? Does it have a part number or datasheet?

Comment: The vendor product page of the top image describes which components are used.

Comment: @jippie this is one of the modules i order  http://www.ebay.com/itm/201052209891?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT and i also order a sort of replacement mic like the one from the one found in this page (single button mic) but i dont need a pot i just need the signal wire so that i can read from it using the arduino analog read pin

Comment: @VicenteCunha sorry i dont if i did i think that would have been a better solution but i still be asking myself HOW to get that 3rd sig wire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, Electret microphones capsules needs a "pull-up" resistor, like this example taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret_microphone):

[image: Electret microphone example]

This should be very similar to the schematics of your board.

Comment: is their a tutorial i can follow to solder this ? i have all the passive components but im not clear about the schematic because altho i can read it i cant be forsure and i actually ordered this one from ebay http://www.ebay.com/itm/201052209891?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT but as you noticed from the main question i also ordered the single Electret microphones capsules  because i want to build my own setups BUT without the actual pot like in the one from the link and also without the pcb, im just going to hot glues it after soldering

Comment: You can read some tutorials on the internet. [This one](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-read-a-schematic) was the first on a Google search.

Answer (score 4):

That is an electret microphone. The basic connection is

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0EFPo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As it says, changing the resistor will change the gain, and you can use any (DC) voltage in the range 2.4 to 5 volts.

It's a very good idea to follow the cap with a high-impedance amplifer.

Comment: so since you schematic looks just like Andy aka below i will just repeat what i told him, " i sorta understand the schematic but i dont quite follow so #1 is the mic right? and between 1 and the 1k resistor theirs a separate wire that goes to a 4.7 micro feraite capacitor ? which interns becomes that signal wire im looking for ?"

Answer (score 1):

The mic you have is here: -

[image]

You can see that one of the pins connects to the case - that is 0V or earth. The other pin is the output/bias point. Connect a resistor between 1k and 10k betweeen the bias point and a DC supply (say 5V). The other end of the DC supply (0V) connects to the case pin.

The output signal will appear on the bias point and you can feed this to a high impedance amplifier via a capacitor: -

[image]

Comment: good looking out on that one, i did not even noticed or consider anything more then just those two soldering points.  Ok so i hear your points and i sorta understand the schematic but i dont quite follow so #1 is the mic right? and between 1 and the 1k resistor theirs a separate wire that goes to a 4.7 micro feraite capacitor ? which interns becomes that signal wire im looking for ?

Comment: Pin 1 is the microphones solder connecter that also connects to the mic chassis (as shown in the picture I modified). Pin 2 is what I called the output/bias point and that connects to a 1 k resistor that you have to supply. The other end of the 1k resistor connects to a supply voltage of about 5V. You then connect a capacitor also to pin 2 and take your output from the capacitor and pin 1 - this goes to your amplifier.

Comment: ok so between 1 and the 1k resistor im going to form something like a voltage divider ?  but rather then use 2 resistor im using a resistor and a capacitor  and from that cap im then going to solder a wire which will become my signal wire or bias as you call it ? also when you say amplifier what do you mean < ? 

 the signal wire im looking to make will and should be going to my arduino analog pin so that i can read the audio/data

Comment: The internal circuit in the electret forms a voltage divider with the 1k. The capacitor is nothing to do with the voltage divider. The capacitor prevents DC flowing to the amplifier (or whatever).

Comment: you keep saying amplifier can you tell me what is it that your calling the amplifier ?

Comment: It's the circuit that receives the tiny signal from the microphone. I call it an amp because the Mic signal on its own needs amplification to make it useful.

Comment: ahhh ok that brings up another new question! what is that other amp component i need? i was under the impression that all i needed was what you and everyone else keep eluding to which is just 2 passive components, i just learned about and downloaded SpiceLT so i want to play around but in order for this to happen i need to account for all the components thanks Andy BTW nice music page!

Comment: are you talking about a OP amp?

Comment: Thanks for visiting LOL. You'll get a few milli volts from the mic under normal close speaking conditions and you need to decide ultimately how much you want to amplify this signal. I can't tell you that - you have to decide but, a common method is to use an op-amp and go for a non-inverting op-amp like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/t9h4y.png

Comment: Thanks i think i have enough to get started! i added your music page on FB add mines if you like when you get a chance and keep rocking !